# Restrict scheduling of Condor jobs: one per physical machine

Tags: networking, cluster-computing, job-scheduling, condor

I need to launch a Condor job on a cluster with multiple slots per machine.

I have an additional requirement that two jobs **can not be placed** at the same time in the same physical machine. This is due to some binary that I can not control which performs some networking (poorly).

This is a somewhat related question: [Limiting number of concurrent processes scheduled by condor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927592/limiting-number-of-concurrent-processes-scheduled-by-condor)
but it does not completely solves my problem. I understand I could restrict where jobs can run in the following way: `Requirements =  (name == "slot1@machine1") || (name == "slot1@machine2") ...`
However this is too restricting as I don't care which slot the jobs run as long as two jobs are not together in the same machine.

Is there a way to achieve this?

If this is not possible how can I tell condor to pick the machine that has the most slots available?

Answer (score -1):

You can try **`condor_status`** command to check the status of the pool of machines.
The first column shows the name of the slots and machines

Now check the `State - Activity`:

- ***`Unclaimed`*** : Slot is idle
- **`Claimed-Busy`** : Slot is running Condor jobs

Comment: How can I use that information in the Job requirement?